# Files Eternally Syncing, Never Uploading Completely on Web

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, sync

I use SharePoint on my computer and it connects with the online version on **Office 365**.  For two days, new files that I save to my computer's SharePoint folder are not uploading onto the web server on **Office 365**.  It always worked automatically before.  Now, when I save a file on my computer's SharePoint folder, there is a blue recycle picture that is permanently there for the new files.  When I go online, the files are not showing up like they should.  Any answers to this question?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of articles on the for that particular question:

- They contain the following characters: & { } ~ # % (there are other illegal characters too, but as they are also blocked from use in Windows Explorer, it is assumed you will not have files named with these characters in your file system.
- They are 128 characters in length or over
- They start with a period character
- They end with a period character
- They contain consecutive period characters

Im still searching for an easy tool to run and show me errors like above, but I found this one: http://get-spscripts.com/2011/11/use-powershell-to-check-for-illegal.html